# Change present modally background, is iPad different to iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

It's incredible, I can't figure this out. I have a "add item" ViewController that is presented modally as form sheet. I want the background to be black. I could set the background directly on the storyboard. It works fine on iPhone but on iPad, no matter what I do, the background is white, and thus I see nothing since the text color is white too. 
I just configured "normally" the background on the storyboard, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you don't have another view which is white somewhere. Use the 3D view hierarchy tool to look at the view layout when you run it in the simulator. Its the icon that looks like a cross made from two rectangles. Its next to the step in step out debug arrows.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that feature. I tried and apparently is that the UITableViewCell is white. The strange thing is that on iPhone I see it as I set it on the storyboard (black, red, whatever). On the iPad I see it always white. [iPhone](http://postimg.org/image/wsf1qj70n/) [iPad](http://postimg.org/image/5t0dvzhlz/)

Comment: Yes for UITableViewCell you have to make sure to set the contentView background rather than the cell background.

Comment: Great!!! thank you now it works. But I don't get why doing so in the code works, and changing the View background in the interface builder seems to work only on iPhone.